# confirmjs popup background dismiss animation is not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was working on Jquery confirm-js popup. Background dismiss animation is not working in firefox latest version. I had debugged jquery-confirm.js plugin file and found that click event was not fired when I click the background space. The code exists in the "jquery-confirm.js" plugin itself and I'm just adding the reference that where I find out the issue. Can anyone help me out, please?

Answer (score 0):

**Default code in the plugin:**

this.$scrollPane = this.$el.find('.jconfirm-scrollpane');

```
this.$scrollPane.click(function(e){
 {
             if(!that.boxClicked){       
                var buttonName = false;
                var shouldClose = false;
                var str;

                if(typeof that.backgroundDismiss === 'function')
                    str = that.backgroundDismiss();
                else
                    str = that.backgroundDismiss;

                if(typeof str === 'string' && typeof that.buttons[str] !== 'undefined'){
                    buttonName = str;
                    shouldClose = false;
                }else if(typeof str === 'undefined' || !!(str) === true){
                    shouldClose = true;
                }else{
                    shouldClose = false;
                }

                if(buttonName){
                    var btnResponse = that.buttons[buttonName].action.apply(that);
                   shouldClose = (typeof btnResponse === 'undefined')|| (btnResponse);
                }

                if(shouldClose)
                    that.close();
                else
                    that.hiLightModal();
            }
            that.boxClicked = false;
        });
```

**Latest Modified Code:**

```
$(document).on('click','.jconfirm-open',function(e){ 
         if(!that.boxClicked){`
                var buttonName = false;
                var shouldClose = false;
                var str;

                if(typeof that.backgroundDismiss === 'function')
                    str = that.backgroundDismiss();
                else
                    str = that.backgroundDismiss;

                if(typeof str === 'string' && typeof that.buttons[str] !== 'undefined'){
                    buttonName = str;
                    shouldClose = false;
                }else if(typeof str === 'undefined' || !!(str) === true){
                    shouldClose = true;
                }else{
                    shouldClose = false;
                }

                if(buttonName){
                    var btnResponse = that.buttons[buttonName].action.apply(that);
                    shouldClose = (typeof btnResponse === 'undefined') || !!(btnResponse);
                }

                if(shouldClose)
                    that.close();
                else
                    that.hiLightModal();
            }
            that.boxClicked = false;
        });
```

The above class ".jquery-scrollPane" click event doesn't work in the firefox browser especially in the latest versions. I have tried to take the parent div class(inspect the popup and u will find out) and applied click event and it worked in all browsers.